# differentiating an inverse function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I have a function $g(x)=\left(e^{5x+x}\right)^2$ which we assume is invertible and are asked to show that its inverse $g^{-1}(x)$ is differentiable and to find its derivative. But it also states that we are not asked to compute the inverse function. How can I find a derivative of an inverse function without knowing what that function is?

Comment: I don't understand what function is. There is a write error.

Comment: @jack you should write g(x)=(e^{5x+x})^2 between the $ signs.

Comment: @jack, are you sure it's $(\exp(5x + x))^2 = (\exp(6x))^2 = \exp(12x)$? Or is there a typo

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

your function is $g(x)=e^{12x}$ so the inverse function is simply $y=\frac{\log x}{12}$, defined for $x>0$. so you can easely find the derivative.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $f(x)$ is invertable, consider
$$y = f(x), \ p = y^{-1}(x),\text{ so }y(p(x)) = x$$

$$1 = \frac{dx}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx}y(p(x)) = y'(p(x))p'(x) = y'(y^{-1}(x))p'(x)$$

So, we can solve for $p'(x)$:
$$p'(x) = (y^{-1})'(x) = \frac{1}{y'(y^{-1}(x))}$$

Answer (score 0):

Given $y=g(x)$you can write
\begin{equation}
\frac{dx}{dy} \frac{dy}{dx}=1 
\end{equation}
Writing explicitly the dependence of y on x
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dx}g^{-1}(x)= \frac{1}{g^{'}(g^{-1}(x))}
\end{equation}